# Check if the order of elements in xml node is correct through xslt 1.0

Tags: xpath, xslt-1.0

I am looking for a solution through xslt 1.0 and x-path 1.0.

Here is a sample xml file:

```
<header>
<number>123</number>
<text>test string</text>
</header>
```

Both number and text are child elements of header node, and both are optional elements in this node.
I want to check through xslt 1.0 whether text element is coming after number element or only child of header node if number element doesnt exist. Same condition goes for number element if text element doesnt exist. Basically i want to make sure the elements should come at their correct location. There can be more child elements with same sceraios. I know XSD can do this but i want to add check like this in xslt 1.0. I havent done anything yet from my side yet. Please suggest if we can do this via xslt 1.0

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit open-ended, but let's interpret as meaning that you want to validate the sequence of children against a content model

A? B? C? D? E?

Here's one way:

```
<xsl:template match="header">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="v"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="A" mode="v">
  <xsl:if test="preceding::sibling::*"><error/></xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="B" mode="v">
  <xsl:variable name="p" select="preceding-sibling::*[1]"/>
  <xsl:if test="$p and not(name($p) = 'A')"><error/></xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="C" mode="v">
  <xsl:variable name="p" select="preceding-sibling::*[1]"/>
  <xsl:if test="$p and not(name($p) = 'A' or name($p) = 'B')"><error/></xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

etc.

Comment: Sorry if my explanation wasn't descriptive but you are right I want to validate the sequence of children against a content model. Thanks, I will try your solution.

Comment: It didn't work, mode 'v' isn't defined anywhere but it is in use template header. Maybe I can find some other solution. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Apart from this if there are 20 child elements then I have to write 20 template matches. Yes, my limitation is xslt 1.0 but there should be a solution to add these kinds of validation checks.

Comment: Edited to add the missing mode declarations. I was going for a solution with maximum flexibility rather than one with maximum brevity. Since you haven't explained why you are doing this in XSLT rather than XSD in the first place, it's hard to guess what your criteria for a good solution are.

Comment: well, i am trying to generate a report through xsl/xsl-fo. My xsl-fo will have these checks and generates error messages in readable format. Thats the criteria of mine.